# Having only binary variables, why is the use of PCA still appropriate?

Tags: pca, correspondence-analysis

I often see the use of PCA on large datasets with a lot of binary variables. As i recall, the computation of the principal components is done via eigenvalue decomposition (or SVD) of the correlation matrix. This often involves the computation of the (pearson's) correlations which includes a standardization of the variables. But computing the correlation matrix is a non-parametric step (?) 
If i would try to measure association between two binary distributed variables, i personally would use other measures.

Jolliffe (2013) is saying that the use of pca for this particular problem should not be a problem. But only as long as its used only for descriptive purpose. Why is that true? I also read about  Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA), would the use of MCA be different in this case?

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

.